# sum of rows with distinct value of one column

Tags: android, sqlite

my table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE "NetworkTransactions" ("uid" INTEGER NOT NULL , "RxStart" INTEGER, "RxEnd" INTEGER, "TxStart" INTEGER, "TxEnd" INTEGER, "StartTS" INTEGER, "EndTS" INTEGER)
```

i want to add difference of RxEnd & RxStart where uid is unique.

Currently I am able to sum the difference but it also sums up the values for different occurrence of uid, which are one and the same. what I need to modify in the given query?

```
Cursor cursor = db.query("NetworkTransactions",
                            new String[] { "sum(RxEnd - RxStart) AS sum" }, null, null, "uid",
                            "sum > 0", "sum", null);
```

basically, I want to write a query equivalent to :

```
select sum(RxEnd - RxStart) as sum from (select DISTINCT uid, RxStart, RxEnd from NetworkTransactions) where sum > 0
```

input table:

```
uid RxStart RxEnd 
1   100     200
2   100     150
1   100     200
2   100     150
4   400     500
6   200     600
```

expected output:
sum of rows with unique row id as corresponding values are just duplicated

```
uid RxStart RxEnd   Diff(RxEnd - RxStart)
1   100     200     100
2   100     150     50
4   400     500     100
6   200     600     400
________________________
sum                 650
```

Comment: please elaborate your question.....or write Sql Query put Limit 1 at the end of query

Comment: you can use  Limit to get only one record at time

Comment: @koutuk see the last part of the question, i updated it.

Comment: select sum(RxEnd - RxStart) as sum from (select DISTINCT uid, RxStart, RxEnd from NetworkTransactions) as temp

Comment: As your query is more complex (has subquery), use [db.rawQuery(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)

Comment: If koutuk's query is not correct, show some example data and the desired output.

Comment: @CL. please check now

Comment: What is wrong with koutuk's query?

Comment: DO you want to get one row for each `uid`, or the total sum?

Comment: @CL. yet it worked with rawQuery

Comment: @koutuk u can add this as answer.

Comment: @ay89 thanks hope my little knowledge helps you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select sum(RxEnd - RxStart) as sum from (select DISTINCT uid, RxStart, RxEnd from NetworkTransactions) as temp

---

Try above Query